# chrome extension activeTab permission to executeScript in frames

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to avoid using the `<all_urls>` permission since I theoretically only need the `activeTab` permission, especially to avoid waiting one week every time Google has to review my extension's new releases.

However, it seems that I cannot use chrome.tabs.executeScript() directly into the tabs' frames without the `<all_urls>` permission.

```js
// background.js

chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  {
    frameId: frame.frameId,
    code: `
      var videoTag = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
      console.log("videotag:", videoTag)
      if (videoTag.length > 0) {
        var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text;
        var ok = true;
        [ok, title];
      }`
  }
)
```

The code above never gets executed with only `activeTab` permission specified, but works well with `<all_urls>` permission.

Is the `activeTab` permission completely useless when it comes to access cross-origin frames in the "active tab"? In that case, do I have any other solution to achieve the same goal without using the `<all_urls>` permission?

Furthermore, since I do not specify the tabId in which I want to execute the script, this implicitly means that I want to execute it in the "active tab":

> integer - (optional) tabId - The ID of the tab in which to run the script; defaults to the active tab of the current window.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Comment: activeTab doesn't grant access to frames in Chrome, see https://crbug.com/826433#c8

Comment: @wOxxOm That sucks, but thanks! Feel free to write an answer so that I can actually accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activeTab` doesn't just mean "whatever tab is on screen, you have access to it"

A tab becomes "active" when the user invokes your extension when they're using it. Refer to the [documentation for `activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab)

> The following user gestures enable activeTab:
>
> - Executing a browser action
> - Executing a page action
> - Executing a context menu item
> - Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
> - Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API

Comment: Yes of course, I understand that, but the code snippet shown above is only triggered when the user triggers a specific action in the popup. So that means that the code is only executed in the "active tab".